# making a multi column dataframe into a single column dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like this

```
  one two three four five
0  a   e    i    m    q
1  b   f    j    n    r   ...
2  c   g    k    o    s
3  d   h    l    p    t
```

and i want to make it something like

```
   one
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
6   g
7   h
8   i
9   j
...
```

in the real case there is like hundreds of columns (but fixed rows) and i only need the first column left with all the values adding below. How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(value_name='one')[['one']]
```

Or [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('one')
```

Or [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one': np.ravel(df,order='F')})
print (df1)
  one
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
7    h
8    i
9    j
10   k
11   l
12   m
13   n
14   o
15   p
16   q
17   r
18   s
19   t
```